# MSVCRT printf never do thousand separator grouping, right?

Tags: locale, msvcrt, setlocale

On Windows, using Microsoft CRT library(MSVCRT), printf/_snprintf/_snprintf_s/_snprintf_s_l etc do consider current thread's CRT locale somehow, but they do NOT do any thousand separator grouping right?

I try the code below:

```
int i1 = 7654321;
double d1 = 1234567.89;
char *locret = nullptr;

setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

locret = setlocale(LC_ALL, "en-US");
assert(locret);
printf("en-US: %d | %.3f\n", i1, d1);

locret = setlocale(LC_ALL, "de-DE");
assert(locret);
printf("de-DE: %d | %.3f\n", i1, d1);
```

Compile the code in VS2019, I see that decimal point character varies with "en-US" and "de-DE". In Germany, people use comma as decimal point.

```
en-US: 7654321 | 1234567.890
de-DE: 7654321 | 1234567,890
```

But you see, thousand-grouping does NOT happen.

[image: Snap1971 vs2019 CRT locale thousep no effect.png]

From the `lconv` struct returned by [localeconv()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localeconv?view=msvc-170), there is information about grouping, `.grouping=0x03`. Looks like this `.grouping` info is never actually used by MSVCRT internally, instead, our application code has to digest this info and do grouping ourselves, right?

**What I'd like to ask is: Does Microsoft ever provide any document listing which "locale properties" are actually implemented, and which are not?**

If no such clear info is provided, I think we should avoid relying on those "culture" property provided by CRT-layer, instead, using another herd of locale functions from [Winnls.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/) (WinAPI-layer) may be a better promise. For example, `SetThreadLocale()` sets/changes WinAPI-layer current thread-locale, then [GetNumberFormat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getnumberformatw), and we will see thousand separator applied.

### ==== Update ====

Well, now I get it. MSDN tolds it, but the wording is tricky.

[image: Snap1973 LC_NUMERIC trick.png]

The thousand separator character is only reflected in the `lconv` struct returned by `localeconv()`; it does not affect `printf` behavior. So, `.grouping` not affecting `printf' is unsurprising as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: MSVCRT printf never do thousand separator grouping, right?**

Right. There's an extension from the Single UNIX Specification which adds thousands' separators when the `'` flag is provided. But this isn't implemented by MSVCRT.

**Q: Does Microsoft ever provide any document listing which "locale properties" are actually implemented, and which are not?**

Newer versions of MSVCRT strictly follow the C standard. The C11 standard says about `setlocale`:

> LC_COLLATE affects the behavior of the strcoll and strxfrm functions. LC_CTYPE affects the behavior of the character handling functions and the multibyte and wide character functions. LC_MONETARY affects the monetary formatting information returned by the localeconv function. LC_NUMERIC affects the decimal-point character for the formatted input/output functions and the string conversion functions, as well as the nonmonetary formatting information returned by the localeconv function. LC_TIME affects the behavior of the strftime and wcsftime functions.

This is also spelled out in [Microsoft's documentation of the setlocale function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale).

Note that most of the information returned by localeconv (especially anything related to monetary values) is never used by any of the C library functions. This is by design. I think only `decimal_point` is actually used.